# IntelliJ: multi-module scala (SBT) project source code refactoring

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, sbt

IntelliJ provides a handy support for **refactoring** a maven multi-module project via the `Add Maven Projects` command.  Is there a similar option for Scala (SBT) projects.

p.s. my current workaround is to convert a scala project from sbt to maven build; and then include it as a module in maven project.

Comment: I haven't seen it in the latest version of IDEA 13.1 CE EAP. What about opening `build.sbt` and adding `lazy val projectName = project`?  IDEA will refresh the build configuration then, and SBT creates the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attaching an existing SBT project to current one? It is possible from SBT tool window:

[image: http://imageshack.us/a/img21/8820/h8nw.png].

There is also an issue ([SCL-6625](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-6625)) about incorrect module dependencies in SBT projects.
The answer was provided by Andrey from JetBrains/IntelliJ Support.